# How can I programatically set the IP address of a hardware device that doesn't already have an IP set

Tags: networking, embedded

We have developed a hardware device that doesn't have a screen.  It uses TCP/IP to communicate with the network.  Currently this is configured by DHCP.

However, we'd like a way to configure it's IP statically by some app I'll have to develop.   I notice for some devices like printers there are custom apps that they use to set such information.  But how do they talk to the device when the device hasn't been assigned an IP already?

Are they using RAW sockets and a custom protocol?  or is there a simpler method.  For example, I recall many years ago using a Linux device that somehow received it's initial IP by running an arping.  But I don't understand how that sets the IP for other hosts on the network.  Nevertheless it seemed to work.  Could I mimick that?

e.g.   arp -s 191.168.2.2 00-40-9d-22-23-60

So I've got an idea how it works, but I'd like to know what is the common method of setting IP to an embedded device that has no physical screen to configure this.

To be clear, this device does not use Linux.

Comment: "_I recall many years ago using a Linux device that somehow received it's initial IP by running an arping._" I think you mean RARP (Reverse Address Resolution Protocol), which was obsoleted by BOOTP, which, in turn, was updated/replaced by DHCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard-conformant way of doing this goes (for IPv4, but IPv6 is similar) along the lines of:

1. Try to obtain an IP address via DHCP, skip step (2) if that worked. This should be the default.
2. If no DHCP server responded, use a unique *link-local address* (These are addresses from the block 169.254.0.0/16 reserved for this purpose. Some parts of the chosen address should be based on something unique to the device, like the MAC address, to make sure the device always chooses the same LL address. Or, to make it fully RFC-compliant: choose a truly random address from this range and probe it - Re-use it when possible) The chosen LL address should be checked against any other use in this network before usage with an arp request on that address (That's probably what you have read). If someone responds to that request, choose a different IP and retry.
3. Now that you have a temporary IP address, you can use one of the various IP-Multicast-based [service discovery protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) to advertise your device to the network.

Comment: "_to make sure the device always chooses the same LL address_" That is actually against the RFC: "_When a host wishes to configure an IPv4 Link-Local address, it selects an address using a pseudo-random number generator with a uniform distribution in the range from 169.254.1.0 to 169.254.254.255 inclusive._"

Comment: @RonMaupin Right - but it's common practice, apparently, especially for platforms that don't have a reliable PRNG. I guess that requirement is not so much a technical requirement rather than for security. (Inability to guess the address and spoof it.)

Comment: @RonMaupin   I recall it was an axis development board.  And the process was exactly like this in method 2  https://www.axis.com/support/faq/FAQ2551.  That doesn't look like RARP to me.

Comment: @Matt I have browsed that site: The methods this device uses seem to be broken, disconforming with RFCs, and will *maybe* work in a sunny day scenario. I would strictly discourage you from using those methods in a consumer device. Apparently, the device listens to arp messages with its own MAC address and sets its IP address accordingly. If you use this with an IP address already used in your network, or someone spoofs that MAC, things go entirely haywire. Also, repeated tries to set the IP of the device will fill your network's arp caches with bogus entries.

Comment: This is a dangerous mis-use of the arp mechanism. And a pre-configured default static IP. Argh. There are *reasons* why people have invented more complicated zero-conf methods.

Comment: Interesting.  Well I think I've got enough to go on thanks.  Will do something custom with raw sockets.  The hardware is very cut down.  No OS but some libs.